# Weird behavior with char/uint8 arrays

Tags: c++, i2c, string

So I'm trying to read an 8-byte character string from an I2C device and print it to the serial console. This raw 8-char array is *not* terminated when it comes from the device, so I'm pretty sure I need to manually terminate it. Unfortunately, when I go to print the resultant string, the serial monitor just fills up with line breaks. Could someone take a look at this code and tell me where I went wrong?

```
uint8_t* HT_Controller::readMultiple(uint8_t reg, uint8_t num)
{
    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddr);
    Wire.write(reg);
    Wire.endTransmission();

    Wire.requestFrom(i2cAddr, num);
    uint8_t* data = new uint8_t[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        data[i] = Wire.read();
    }

    return data;
}

char* HT_Controller::getManufacturer()
{
    uint8_t* data = readMultiple(REGISTER_MFR, NUM_MFR_BYTES); //Read the bytes from the controller
    char* dataTerminated = new char[NUM_MFR_BYTES + 1]; //Our new array that will have a null char at the end
    memcpy(data, dataTerminated, NUM_MFR_BYTES); //Copy the bytes into the new array
    delete(data); //We're done with the original array, remove it from the heap
    dataTerminated[NUM_MFR_BYTES] = 0; //Add that null char. NB: we don't need to '+1' the index because arrays start at 0, not 1

    return dataTerminated;
}
```

And here's how it's used in the main sketch:

```
void loop()
{
    char* data = mc1->getManufacturer();
    Serial.println(data);
    delete(data);
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Hint#1: Check the parameter order for memcpy(), http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/. And try writing code without all the heap usage (new/delete).

Comment: @MikaelPatel how can I avoid heap usage, keeping in mind this is for a library?

Comment: Hint#2: Use the stack and pass return values by reference. e.g. "char dataTerminated[NUM_MFR_BYTES + 1]; readMultiple(REGISTER_MFR, NUM_MFR_BYTES, dataTerminated);"

Comment: @MikaelPatel wait but isn't returning a pointer to a local array a no-no?

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean now

Comment: @MikaelPatel hmm so that's all well and good for `readMultiple()`, but in order to apply that to `getManufacturer()` the user would need to know that the array they pass in to be outputed to needs to be 9 chars big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memcpy is backwards.

```
SYNOPSIS
   #include <string.h>

   void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

So the line:

```
memcpy(data, dataTerminated, NUM_MFR_BYTES); //Copy the bytes into the new array
```

should be:

```
memcpy(dataTerminated, data, NUM_MFR_BYTES); //Copy the bytes into the new array
```